# Is there an appropriate place to post links and comments?

Tags: support

Is there a place on MSE where one can post interesting non-interrogative math stuff? Like for instance this amazing thing that I'm sure everyone on this site would benefit from (and of which I suspect everyone is already aware): http://webdemo.visionobjects.com/equation.html

Comment: That is pretty neat!

Answer (score 9):

That site may fall under "useful tools or resources for the mathematically inclined" and hence could be a good candidate for [community ads](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/community-promotion-ads-2012).

But other than specifically mathematical links that fits the community ad scheme, for generally sharing of awesome stuff I refer you to Google+, Twitter, Reddit, or your own personal blog for that.

Comment: ...and if you make a community ad out of it, it should hopefully get more exposure than it already has.

Comment: ok thanks I'll put it up for a community ad.

Answer (score 2):

You could post it as an answer to [Resources for getting maths on to the web](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012/resources-for-getting-maths-on-to-the-web). It might fit as an answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2147/most-helpful-math-resources-on-the-web