# Community Promotion Ads — 2020

Tags: discussion, community-ads

2020 has come! But… oops, where did the time go? It’s already March! Belated as it is, it’s time for a refresh of **Community Promotion Ads**!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- useful tools or resources for the mathematically inclined
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 × 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ads/display/31296).

Answer (score 46):

[image: Approach0.xyz]

Comment: [Repost](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29670/community-promotion-ads-2019#answer-29716) from last year.

Comment: I don't like this approach.

Answer (score 40):

[image: Overleaf: Free online collaborative LaTeX editor with real-time PDF preview]

Comment: It is not accessible for Iranian users (perhaps duo to US embargooooo!)

Answer (score 34):

[image: Sage Mathematical Software Environment]

Comment: Reposting [last year's version](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29670/community-promotion-ads-2019/29678#29678).

Answer (score 30):

[image: Create, animate, and share beautiful math in your browser]

Comment: BTW: I am the primary creator/maintainer of math3d.org, though definitely believe this site is of interest to the MSE community. The project is on github and Open source on the MPL 2.0 license. github.com/ChristopherChudzicki/math3d-react

Comment: A really good site. Is there a documentation available?

Answer (score 30):

[image: web-gui to get tikz-cd code for commutative diagrams]

Comment: I'll bite.  What is this about?

Comment: It simplifies the typesetting of commutative diagrams by providing a web-gui which returns the tikz-cd code of the diagram.

Comment: Without more information in the picture, I don't think this is suitable for a community ad - if you can rework the image to give more of a description, you may have a better chance of getting it accepted.

Comment: @KReiser I agree, I would rework the picture if it would be my project or if I had at least any kind of talent regarding ad design.

Comment: I've drawn <10 commutative diagrams in my entire life...but I've dumped some words on it (using the XITS font), and also added a 2px border as required in the Question https://imgur.com/6ffhY0h . If people prefer this then someone can edit this into the Answer.

Comment: Actually the image is not even in the correct dimensions, so I'll go ahead and change it to this newer version https://imgur.com/3P6jET2 ... if you don't look too closely then the grid at the back looks OK

Answer (score 26):

[image: Real Not Complex - Free Resources to Study Mathematics]

Answer (score 24):

[image: Mathematics Educators Beta]

Comment: [Source of the picture](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: I came from the ad, but what about linking to the question shown in the ad?

Answer (score 23):

[image: GAP - Group, Algorithms and Programming]

Comment: Repost from [the previous year](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27816/70316)

Answer (score 15):

[image: Collaborative Calculation in the Cloud]

Comment: Reposting [last year's version](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29670/community-promotion-ads-2019/29679#29679).

Answer (score 14):

[image: Open-access web platform for open problems in mathematics]

Comment: I think this has the nicest design of all the ones I've seen.

Answer (score 13):

[image: KaTeX.org]

Comment: Never ever got 4 upvotes and 4 downvotes simultaneously...sorry for dividing you in two parties!! Now seriously, I have quite understood that SE uses/endorses MathJax, this may load faster but I tried both so, in the lucky case I will need'em again, I know how to handle the former and the latter ;)

Comment: I did not vote either up or down, but this ad is not in the right format (and I expect it wouldn't show). Check the sizing requirements.

Comment: As for the downvotes, my guess is that it may be because this seems to be something that programmers, not mathematicians, will use. It seems out of place to me. A mathematician may use something built with KaTeX, but in the end KaTeX itself is just a building block for software developers.

Comment: @Szabolcs Interesting, yes, and I don't matter downvotes themselves, suggestions in comments are way more useful! When I was attending BSc in Maths, I was asked to publish a whole website with exercises about a topic in Algebra ([this one!](http://progettomatematica.dm.unibo.it/estensionecampi/home.html)) and if I could ever know either KaTeX or MathJax I would fly ;)

Comment: @Szabolcs anyway thank you, image updated to fit...dimension and dimensions!

Comment: Good point about exercise sites, I had to do those too, and I used tex4ht (a very long time ago). +1

Comment: It's a bit funny, considering that this site uses MathJaX :P But KaTeX is a great tool.

Comment: @Trebor yeah but we do not follow the fashion, we go against the wave ;)

Answer (score 11):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Network analysis and graph theory package for Mathematica]

Comment: Why the -1? It's an open-source graph theory tool. This is an appropriate venue for showing it.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Combinatorics]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: Computational/numerical modeling for the design of: solar cells, photovoltaics, superconductors for quantum computing, better semi-conductors for computer hardware, bio-materials, organic LEDs for smartphone screens (same brightness while being less susceptible to cracking), new materials for better batteries, energy storage materials, molecular magnets, energy conversion materials, stronger and lighter materials for cars, bikes, planes, spaceships, etc. Solutions to huge Schrödinger equations, Density Functional Theory, mathematics of solid-state physics and **applied** quantum theory.

Comment: Unfortunately, suggested edits can't be made on meta sites, so you will have to edit this one.