# Community ads link to old meta post

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

I think I've come across a very mild bug. When I click on the `comments` or `stats` links on a community ad, it links me to the [voting page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31296/community-promotion-ads-2020#31309) and [stats page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/31296) for 2020, rather than the 2021 [voting page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33720/community-ads-for-2021) and [stats page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/33720). It also appears that clicks are not being logged on the new stats page. Probably the links just need to be updated to fix this.